# Why has he used the progressive form?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> [...] and a word that a lot of native speakers get wrong in spite of it being so common.

Why has the author used "to be" in the progressive form?

I would expect "is" instead, or "be" as subjunctive. What kind of sentence is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In spite of* is used with a noun ("We set out in spite of the bad weather"). *Being* here is a gerund taking the place of a noun.

The writer could have said "...even though it is so common."